# Running main method from test class via maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
   ...
   <plugins>
   ...
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.myorg.MyClass</mainClass>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

The class `com.myorg.MyClass` is in my test source directory, and I am able to run it with the following command:

```
mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="test"
```

I want to:

1. avoid having to use `-Dexec.classpathScope="test"`, but I cannot work out how configure that plugin to look in the test classpath.
2. write more plugins for other classes (which will each have different configurations), but right now I can only run `exec:java`. Is there a way to label this plugin so that I call it via that label rather than just say "run whatever is in exec:java"?
3. pull in a `-javaagent` property. I have this property defined in my pom.xml, which is being used by test cases. Will my "custom" plugin pick up these properties or do I need to do anything to pull them in?

Here is the properties, which is defined directly under `<project>`.

```
<properties>
   <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
   <atomikos.version>3.9.2</atomikos.version>
   <loadTimeWeaverArgLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar"</loadTimeWeaverArgLine>
</properties>
```

## Attempt with profile

Following on @Michal's suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839824/257233) this is what I have tried:

```
<profile>
   <id>run-importer</id>
   <properties>
      <loadTimeWeaverArgLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar"</loadTimeWeaverArgLine>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <executable>java</executable>
                  <!--
                     None of these three options work.
                     <commandlineArgs>-javaagent:C:/Users/robbram/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar</commandlineArgs>
                     <commandlineArgs>${loadTimeWeaverArgLine}</commandlineArgs>
                     <commandlineArgs>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar"</commandlineArgs>
                     <argLine>${loadTimeWeaverArgLine}</argLine>
                  -->
               <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
               <mainClass>com.myorg.MyClass</mainClass>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</profile>
```

I run it with:

```
mvn -e exec:java -Prun-importer
```

I am getting the following exception with either of the options:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project TOLTAT-Model: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver' defined in class org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project TOLTAT-Model: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
```

I can confirm that the main class `com.myorg.MyClass` is being executed. I can see other output from it. I can also confirm that `loadTimeWeaverArgLine` works in other parts of this POM. It is used successfully for Integration tests:

```
<profile>
   <id>integration-tests</id>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <!-- Integration tests require additional loadtime Spring argument -->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
               <forkMode>once</forkMode>
               <argLine> ${loadTimeWeaverArgLine}</argLine>
               <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</profile>
```

## Attempt 2 with profile and mvn exec:exec

Upodate (Wednesday, 17th of June 2015, 12:11:17 PM): Following on [Michal's latest comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839272/running-main-method-from-test-class-via-maven#comment49779516_30839824) I now have this working as I want:

```
<profile>
   <id>run-importer</id>
   <properties>
      <loadTimeWeaverArg>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar"</loadTimeWeaverArg>
      <log4JConfigArg>-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${project.build.directory}/path/to/log4j.properties</log4JConfigArg>
      <mainClassArg>com.myorg.MyClass</mainClassArg>
      <arg1>foo</arg1>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <goals>
               <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <executable>java</executable>
               <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
               <arguments>
                  <argument>${log4JConfigArg}</argument>
                  <argument>${loadTimeWeaverArg}</argument>
                  <argument>-classpath</argument>
                  <classpath />
                  <argument>${mainClassArg}</argument>
                  <argument>${arg1}</argument>
               </arguments>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</profile>
```

And I run it with:

```
mvn -e exec:exec -Prun-importer
```

The advantages of this approach:

- The whole purpose of this profile is to run "special code" that should never be deployed but needs to make use of code in src and test src.

  - I note Michal's suggestion that this deserves to be a module by itself. If this code base wasn't already so well established (large, old, complicated), I would seriously consider this.
- It leaves room in case this ever needs to be duplicated, so there is no "competition" regarding what gets run with `mvn -e exec:exec`.
- I can specify java agent, log4j and lots of other config using variables that already exist in the pom.
- I can override any of these arguments on the command line with `-Darg1="bar"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're actually going to accomplish by this since it's quite stilted use of Maven. However, all this stuff is technically possible:

1/

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.myorg.MyClass</mainClass>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2/

You can use profiles for that and put different plugin configurations in different profile. Then you call:

```
mvn -e exec:java -Pmy-first-profile
```

It's really weird however, I think. My recommendation here is to reconsider your case and maybe pick another way or tool for that.

3/

*Final solution in the question itself after the author's edit.*

Comment: Thanks Michal, I will try this first thing in the morning. I wanted to explain my reasoning for using Maven though. This is a pre existing project with a lot of configuration in Maven already. My code needs a lot of that configuration plus it uses the classes in the src directory, but my code is also something of a special case that should never be deployed (thus it is in the test dir). I didn't want to use a different tool because then I would have to figure out how to duplicate all the config that is already there.

Comment: OK, got it. For such cases where test codebase is quite complex and possibly usable on its own (for whatever reason) I really recommend going with separate Maven module (e.g. `my-superb-project-testing-support`) where all testing stuff (`junit`, `mockito`, supporting classes, builders, etc.) is put into `src/main/java` tree. Such a module can be used then in other (business) modules as test-scoped dependency.

Comment: Well, the first two parts are solved, but the third is killing me. I have updated my question to show what I have tried so far.

Comment: For your updated description, call `mvn -e exec:exec -Prun-importer` instead of `mvn exec:java ...`

Comment: Thank you very much - based on your advice, I have finally worked out how to solve all the issues I was experiencing. :)